# Can I leave Family sharing on one device while staying on the other?

Tags: apple-id, family-sharing

I'd like my MacBook to stay on the family plan while removing my iPhone from the family plan. Both of these devices are under the same Apple ID. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Family sharing membership is attached with Apple ID not with individual device(s). If you remove an Apple ID from family sharing, it is applicable everywhere that Apple ID is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Clarification on Nimesh's correct answer: *If* your goal in asking the question is to prevent downloads to the iPhone from being available to other members of the Family Share, you can control that for each download. A quick search online returned the [Family Share information page](https://www.apple.com/family-sharing/). It explains you can hide purchases to prevent them from appearing in the purchased list on other devices (which includes your purchased list on other members' devices). To hide your downloads the instructions include a link to [Hide apps for your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, or Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201322).